# bring image besides headline on the left & right side in tailwind css without using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, css-position

I want to bring the image next to my headline. It shouldn't take up headline space but should be beside it.

Either the left side or the right side. specifically, the square image should be where I have shown the black circle. Just beside the headline.

[image: image demo]

I can't use Flexbox here.

I also don't want to use absolute positioning since I have 20+ images I have to show on the landing page.

I have a working code for absolute positioning but it requires lots of calculation. specifically, I have to calculate `translate-y` from top so there's lots of `translate-y-[20%]`, `translate-y-[139%]`, etc...

I also mostly cannot change the layout since I use [@tailwind/typography](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) which requires a specific layout.

Every child should be below `.prose` class.

I have `img` just below `h2` that I want to be on the side of `h2`, either the left or right side, alternatively.

the code looks like this:

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<main class="flex min-h-screen bg-gray-900">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),1fr] gap-8 overflow-auto p-8 [&>*]:col-start-2">
    <div class="prose grid grid-cols-[70px_1fr_70px] border-8 border-red-400 bg-gray-100 [&>*]:col-start-2">
      <h2>this is my first headline</h2>
      <img class="h-32 w-32" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?blur" alt="temp img 1" />
      <p>i want to make the image come besides the headline</p>
      <p>i don't want to use absolute positioning unless</p>
      <p>i can make sure the images come on the side of headline</p>
      <p>i have a landing page with 20+ images</p>
      <p>and i want them on the left & right side of each `h2` tag</p>
      <p>they must not overlap with `h2` but be on the edges of the red border</p>
      <h2>this is my second headline</h2>
      <img class="h-32 w-32" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?blur" alt="temp img 2" />
      <p>i want the first image on the right side</p>
      <p>and the second one on the left side</p>
      <p>how do i do it?</p>
      <p>i tried using translate-x & relative positioning with no luck</p>
      <p>i want it to be in a way that i don't have to use top-[300px] or some random position</p>
      <p>i don't want to keep calculating</p>
      <p>ideally, i'd love to keep the same structure of `h2` & `img` as siblings</p>
      <p>if its not possible, i'd love to have a `h2` & `img` wrapped in a `div`</p>
      <p>or better version would be `img` (absolute) wrapped inside `h2` with a `relative` position</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I have shown 2 images but I have 20+ images in my actual landing page.

I have also given an explanation within the code itself.

the demo can be seen on tailwind play → https://play.tailwindcss.com/oxshT4UNKX (edit code & click share to share the latest version)

I want to avoid calculation if at all possible in a way that the image stays on the left & right sides of the red border.

how do I do it without changing the layout?

I think `div.relative.flex > {h2,img}` would be a worse layout but `h2.relative > img.absolute` would be much better to work with `@tailwind/typography`

Comment: why can you not use Flexbox? Tailwind works with flexboxes anyways. Why not `float` the images?

Comment: Why are you using grid classes on the container, for that kind of layout? And can you change the code? I would ditch grid layout here, and simply float the images. If you can't put them _before_ the headlines in the source code, then you will have to drag them up a bit using a negative margin-top (although you will need a "magic number" for that, and it won't work if a headline goes over multiple lines.)

Comment: @tacoshy i have trouble getting float to work. how would i do it so that it comes to the side of the border?

Comment: @CBroe i was using this layout for my blog so copied the same html & css. not sure why that matters bcz that doesn't affect what i want to achieve anyways? i did try removing grid but was unsuccessful as i haven't used css for long so got a bit rusty. if i need a magic number, then i might as well go with translate-y for which i have working code. i thought there would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: _"not sure why that matters bcz that doesn't affect what i want to achieve anyways?"_ - how does it not affect what you want to achieve? If you want to do this using a grid layout - well then you'd have to make it a _different_ grid, one that actually places the images where you want them.

Comment: @tacoshy floats wrap besides text, right? i don't want that. see the image in my question. i want the image to be beside the headline.

Comment: @CBroe wow, you're right. i did try using `col-[3/4]` for `left` image & `col-[1/2]` for right image & can place them in appropriate rows using `row-[24]` but is there any way to increase the size of the image. now they are appropriately placed but shrunk in size.

Comment: @CBroe i changed from using grid to simplifying it & found a solution. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the grid layout, you could modify the grid column tracks such that there is sufficient width for the images, and then position the headings and images as desired:

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=typography"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<main class="flex min-h-screen bg-gray-900">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),1fr] gap-8 overflow-auto p-8 [&>*]:col-start-2">
    <div class="prose grid grid-cols-[70px_calc(theme(spacing.32)-70px)_1fr_calc(theme(spacing.32)-70px)_70px] border-8 border-red-400 bg-gray-100 [&>*]:col-start-2 [&>*]:col-span-3 grid-flow-dense">
      <h2 class="!col-start-2 !col-span-2">this is my first headline</h2>
      <img class="h-32 w-32 !col-start-4 !col-span-2" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?blur" alt="temp img 1" />
      <p>i want to make the image come besides the headline</p>
      <p>i don't want to use absolute positioning unless</p>
      <p>i can make sure the images come on the side of headline</p>
      <p>i have a landing page with 20+ images</p>
      <p>and i want them on the left & right side of each `h2` tag</p>
      <p>they must not overlap with `h2` but be on the edges of the red border</p>
      <h2 class="!col-start-3 !col-span-2">this is my second headline</h2>
      <img class="h-32 w-32 !col-start-1 !col-span-2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?blur" alt="temp img 2" />
      <p>i want the first image on the right side</p>
      <p>and the second one on the left side</p>
      <p>how do i do it?</p>
      <p>i tried using translate-x & relative positioning with no luck</p>
      <p>i want it to be in a way that i don't have to use top-[300px] or some random position</p>
      <p>i don't want to keep calculating</p>
      <p>ideally, i'd love to keep the same structure of `h2` & `img` as siblings</p>
      <p>if its not possible, i'd love to have a `h2` & `img` wrapped in a `div`</p>
      <p>or better version would be `img` (absolute) wrapped inside `h2` with a `relative` position</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Otherwise, you could float the images:

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=typography"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<main class="flex min-h-screen bg-gray-900">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),1fr] gap-8 overflow-auto p-8 [&>*]:col-start-2">
    <div class="prose border-8 border-red-400 bg-gray-100 px-[70px]">
      <img class="h-32 w-32 float-right -mr-[70px]" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?blur" alt="temp img 1" />
      <h2>this is my first headline</h2>
      <p>i want to make the image come besides the headline</p>
      <p>i don't want to use absolute positioning unless</p>
      <p>i can make sure the images come on the side of headline</p>
      <p>i have a landing page with 20+ images</p>
      <p>and i want them on the left & right side of each `h2` tag</p>
      <p>they must not overlap with `h2` but be on the edges of the red border</p>
      <img class="h-32 w-32 float-left -ml-[70px]" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?blur" alt="temp img 2" />
      <h2>this is my second headline</h2>
      <p>i want the first image on the right side</p>
      <p>and the second one on the left side</p>
      <p>how do i do it?</p>
      <p>i tried using translate-x & relative positioning with no luck</p>
      <p>i want it to be in a way that i don't have to use top-[300px] or some random position</p>
      <p>i don't want to keep calculating</p>
      <p>ideally, i'd love to keep the same structure of `h2` & `img` as siblings</p>
      <p>if its not possible, i'd love to have a `h2` & `img` wrapped in a `div`</p>
      <p>or better version would be `img` (absolute) wrapped inside `h2` with a `relative` position</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: this is close but in both answers, the second headline moves a bit. i don't want the text to move at all. the idea is to get the images besides headlines but not break the text flow at all. is this possible at all? is it possible with grid layout? or do i need another layout? further, i want the images on the border, not just besides headline as that's where my illustrations would be.

Comment: i found a solution that i've posted. made it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the layout to not use grid & found a solution quickly that doesn't depend on absolute positioning.

```html
<main class="flex min-h-screen bg-gray-900">
  <div class="dark:prose-light prose prose-lg mx-auto my-4 max-w-[750px] overflow-auto rounded-lg border-8 border-red-400 bg-gray-100 px-24 py-16">
    <h2 class="relative">
      this is my first headline
      <img class="absolute -right-44 -top-24 z-10 h-32 w-32" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?blur" alt="temp img 1" />
    </h2>
    <p>i want to make the image come besides the headline</p>
    <p>i don't want to use absolute positioning unless</p>
    <p>i can make sure the images come on the side of headline</p>
    <p>i have a landing page with 20+ images</p>
    <p>and i want them on the left & right side of each `h2` tag</p>
    <p>they must not overlap with `h2` but be on the edges of the red border</p>
    <h2 class="relative">
      this is my second headline and it works like the best thing in the world
      <img class="absolute -left-44 -top-20 z-10 h-32 w-32" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?blur" alt="temp img 2" />
    </h2>
    <p>i want the first image on the right side</p>
    <p>and the second one on the left side</p>
    <p>how do i do it?</p>
    <p>i tried using translate-x & relative positioning with no luck</p>
    <p>i want it to be in a way that i don't have to use top-[300px] or some random position</p>
    <p>i don't want to keep calculating</p>
    <p>ideally, i'd love to keep the same structure of `h2` & `img` as siblings</p>
    <p>if its not possible, i'd love to have a `h2` & `img` wrapped in a `div`</p>
    <p>or better version would be `img` (absolute) wrapped inside `h2` with a `relative` position</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

the `h2` contains the `img` which i've made `absolute` while `h2` is `relative`... then i used `top`, `left`, & `right` to position themselves.

the tailwind play is here → https://play.tailwindcss.com/yWhtSK9dYX

[image: demo image solution]